# Datatable.net - text-align:left doesn't work

Tags: html, css, html-table, datatables

I have the following table setup (with datatables.net in the background) and I am wondering why I can't left-align my table headings.

```
<table class="display" id="latest_tbl" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                Date
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                User
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:center">
                Status
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:center">
                Date1
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                User2
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:center">
                Date2
            </th>
            <th style="width:10%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                d1
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                u1
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:center">
                stat1
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:center">
                d1
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                u2
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:center">
                d2
            </td>                
            <td style="width:10%">
               <input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-info" disabled />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I just checked it and the "problem" also appears without datatables.net.

Thank you for your help!

PS: To clarify: I would like to have the same setup like in my code example, but in my case it looks like this:

[image]

and I want to have the heading and the content to be aligned in order.

Answer (score 0):

When i understand it right you want to align all headings left but in your code use `text-align: center` And i hope you use inline-styles for showcase purpose :)

```html
<table class="display" id="latest_tbl" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                Date
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                User
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                Status
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                Date1
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                User2
            </th>
            <th style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                Date2
            </th>
            <th style="width:10%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                d1
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                u1
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                stat1
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                d1
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                u2
            </td>
            <td style="width:15%; text-align:left">
                d2
            </td>                
            <td style="width:10%">
               <input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-info" disabled />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No, I would like to keep the setup with a mix of centered and left alignments. I updated my question in order to clarify this :)